# SQL query to get week number from date while setting week starting from Sunday

Tags: sql, datetime, presto, amazon-athena

I am trying to run a query in AWS Athena to get the week number from a date. I need the week to start on Sunday.

I have tried the below query and it works but it considers the week starts from Monday.

```
Extract(week from date) as week_number
```

Google bigquery has an option where you can specify the week start. Eg:

```
Extract(week(Sunday) from date) as week_number
```

Is there something similar in Athena?

Request assistance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there isn't, you can add one day:

```
extract(week from date + interval '1' day) as week_number
```

Comment: How to add 1 day interval. I tried the dateadd function but athena returns an error as dateadd fiunction not registered.